# How do I inherit views in WPF while using MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, inheritance, mvvm, user-controls

I'm somewhat new to WPF and the MVVM pattern.  Here is my situation.  My application looks similar to Outlook (2007).  There is a left navigation pane with a list of editors, and a right content pane where the editors will show up in tabs.  Some of my editors have a very similar look.  They will have a top pane with a grid of items to edit.  Once selecting an item, the bottom pane will will show a form-style editor with text boxes, combo boxes, etc.  I'd like to encapsulate the basic functionality of these editors in a base class.  But, from what I've read, you can't inherit XAML.  One solution I saw someone mention is creating the base UserControl class that has no XAML (only .cs file).  Then, each of my editor's views could inherit off of it and incorporate the editor specific items--particularly the bottom edit pane.  Each of the editor's will have their own view model, but they would also inherit off of a common view model base class.  Is this a good solution or is there a better way.

EDIT:

So my next question is how?  I've created the following base class (with no XAML) that dynamically creates 3 rows.  The first row contains a `DataGrid`.  The base class will define the grid but the sub-classes will set the binding.  The second row simply contains a grid splitter.  And, the third row is empty.  This is where the specific editor will put it's own user control.

```
public class BaseEditor : UserControl
{
  public BaseEditor()
  {
    RowDefinition gridRow = new RowDefinition();
    RowDefinition splitterRow = new RowDefinition();
    RowDefinition editorRow = new RowDefinition();

    _userControlsGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(gridRow);
    _userControlsGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(splitterRow);
    _userControlsGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(editorRow);

    EditorGrid = new DataGrid();
    Grid.SetRow(EditorGrid, 0);
    _userControlsGrid.Children.Add(EditorGrid);

    GridSplitter gridSplitter = new GridSplitter();
    Grid.SetRow(gridSplitter, 1);
    _userControlsGrid.Children.Add(gridSplitter);

    AddChild(_userControlsGrid);
  }
}
```

Then, I have attempted to create a specific editor that inherits from BaseEditor.  I have set the base class in the cs file to BaseEditor, and I have also set the begin/end tags in the xaml to BaseEditor.

I see the controls within the designer of the specific editor.  However, I soon see this is not what I expected.  If I start to add content in the specific editor's XAML, it is not going in the third row.  So, I missing something.  In windows forms, you could create a Content region using attributes and the designer would only be able to edit that area.  How do I do a similar thing in WPF so that all of the content goes into the third row?

Answer (score 0):

I would think of this more like a set of wrapped controls, each with a content section.

If you think of it more like a "Button" then you can sort of get my meaning. A WPF Button has a particular style and layout that is invoked when you stick `<Button>Content</Button>` in your XAML. Each button also has a Content section which determines where in it's XAML your specified content is rendered. Your generic layout can be built so that it's "just a control," like a button, but has the common functinality built in.

Then, you can add your specific content within each one. Your control doesn't need to be a view of it's own, but it can certainly contain views with associated ViewModels as needed.

So, your Tool Pane is a View, with a VM, that has a few "Tool" controls in it, for common layout. Each Tool then has a Content section with each Tool's specific View controls.

Answer (score 0):

Inheriting the views from a custom base class is a great solution for common view-logic. Create specialized UserControls or create advanced templates to create view objects you want to reuse on many views. Then make the UserControls bindable to the views data.